# Installer script not working to add attributes in magento(1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to create custom product type with custom attributes..I am able to create custom product type but getting issues while adding attributes to it. I tried to add the installer script in modules config.xml file,but not working:-

Here is the installer script :-

```
 <?php /** @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */


    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->addAttribute(
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
        'affiliate_link',
        array(
            'type'                    => 'text',
            'backend'                 => '',
            'frontend'                => '',
            'label'                   => 'Affiliate Link',
            'input'                   => 'text',
            'class'                   => '',
            'source'                  => '',
            'global'                  => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible'                 => true,
            'required'                => true,
            'user_defined'            => false,
            'default'                 => '',
            'searchable'              => false,
            'filterable'              => false,
            'comparable'              => false,
            'visible_on_front'        => false,
            'unique'                  => false,
            'apply_to'                => 'gift',
            'is_configurable'         => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => false
        )
    );


    $attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId(
        'catalog_product',
        'affiliate_link'
    );

     $defaultSetId = $installer->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'default');

    $installer->addAttributeGroup(
        'catalog_product',
        $defaultSetId,
        'Affiliate Information'
    );

    //find out the id of the new group
    $groupId = $installer->getAttributeGroup(
        'catalog_product',
        $defaultSetId,
        'Affiliate Information',
        'attribute_group_id'
    );

    //assign the attribute to the group and set
    if ($attributeId > 0) {
        $installer->addAttributeToSet(
            'catalog_product',
            $defaultSetId,
            $groupId,
            $attributeId
        );
    }

    $installer->endSetup();?>
```

Code for config.xml:-

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cueblocks_Newtype>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Cueblocks_Newtype>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <catalog>
            <product>
                <type>
                    <gift translate="label" module="cueblocks_newtype">
                        <label>Gift Product</label>
                        <model>cueblocks_newtype/product_type</model>
                        <is_qty>0</is_qty>
                        <composite>0</composite>
                        <can_use_qty_decimals>0</can_use_qty_decimals>
                    </gift>
                </type>
            </product>
        </catalog>



         <!-- code omitted for brevity -->
                    <blocks>
            <cueblocks_newtype>
                <class>Cueblocks_Newtype_Block</class>
            </cueblocks_newtype>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <cueblocks_newtype>
                <class>Cueblocks_Newtype_Helper</class>
            </cueblocks_newtype>
        </helpers>
                    <models>
            <cueblocks_newtype>
                <class>Cueblocks_Newtype_Model</class>
            </cueblocks_newtype>
        </models>


        <!-- code omitted for brevity -->
                <resources>
            <cueblocks_newtype_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Cueblocks_Newtype</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                  <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
                 </cueblocks_newtype_setup>

                 <newtype_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
</newtype_write>
<newtype_read>
    <connection>
        <use>core_read</use>
    </connection>
</newtype_read> 
 </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: you have not intitlize read and write adpter for this module in config.xml

Comment: @KeyulShah :-Thanks for the response but still it's not working...Also can you please explore what is the role of defining read & write adapters in config file.I have updated the config.xml above by defining these two.

Comment: If you put a `Mage::log()` statement in there do you see something in the logs? That's the easiest way to see f your script gets executed or not.

Comment: What I noticed that it's not even executing the installer script..Is there any other way to check why it's not calling the installer script??

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you give the following a read which goes into in-depth explanation on setting up an explorer script:

[Magento – Install, install upgrade, data and data upgrade scripts](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/)

You haven't defined your resource table names properly nor properly instantiated the installation process. I'd suggest copying that code line-by-line into your code & replacing the namespace & module name with that of your own.

**Edit:** You may also want to take a look at this resource if it's just for a product attribute:

[Magento: add new attribute to all products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599262/magento-add-new-attribute-to-all-products)

Comment: :-Thanks for the link but I don't think  we need to specify the table names in installer scripts to add attributes because I have taken reference from number of sites.But I will try this one...

Comment: Gotcha, let me know if you still run into problems. I edited my answer to also include a link to SO where a similar topic is discussed.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response..Lemme check & will get back to you..

Comment: I have tried but problem with my code is that it's not executing the installer script..I have tried by putting an message & die at starting of file..As per my knowledge whenever we execute some magnto module,it firstly look for the installer files & if found,execute same...I have edited my answer to explain more what exactly I am doing..Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

View how to create install and upgrade scripts here: https://www.sitepoint.com/magento-install-upgrade-data-scripts-explained/

Than make sure that the permissions are enough and the owner is correct for the whole **sql** folder, after that make sure that the module data version in the database table **core_resource** is suitable for the install script to run.